# TypeError: cartItems.map is not a function

Tags: node.js, redux

i have function to post this order for an API, and when i try to map the cart Items. it has an error ." cartItems.map is not a function

```
    createOrder = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const order = {
            name : this.state.name,
            email : this.state.email,
            address : this.state.address,
            cartItems : this.props.cartItems,
            total : this.props.cartItems.reduce(
                ( a, c ) => a + c.price * c.count, 0
            ),
        }   
        this.props.createOrder(order) // 
    };
```

```
const createOrder = ( order ) => (dispatch) => {
    fetch('/api/orders', {
        method : "POST",
        headers : {
            "Content-Type" : "application/json",
        },
        body : JSON.stringify( order ),
    })
        .then( ( res ) => res.json())
        .then( ( data ) => {
            dispatch({
                type : CREATE_ORDER, payload : data
            });
            localStorage.clear('cartItems');
            dispatch({
                type : CLEAR_CART
            });
        });
};
```

and i save the cartItem in local storage like  this :

```
const cartReducer = ( 
    state = { cartItems : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems')) || "[]" },
    action 
) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TO_CART:
            return {
                cartItems : action.payload.cartItems
            }
        case REMOVE_FROM_CART :
                return {
                cartItems : action.payload.cartItems
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

and i post cart item with addToCart function,

```
const addToCart = ( product ) => ( dispatch, getSate ) => {
    const cartItems = getSate().cart.cartItems.slice(); // using  this
    let alreadyExists = false;
    console.log(cartItems);

    cartItems.forEach( ( x ) => {
        if( x._id === product._id ) { 
            alreadyExists = true;
            x.count++;
        }
    });
    if( !alreadyExists ) { 
        cartItems.push({ ...product, count : 1 }); 
    }
    dispatch({
        type : ADD_TO_CART,
        payload : { cartItems }
    });
    localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify( cartItems ));
}
```

but when i check the value of cartItems, i've got an Array for the return of cartItem.

[an Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XspZ1.png)

```
 cartItems.map( (item) => (
     <li key={item._id}>
       <div>
         <img src={ item.image } alt= { item.title } />
       </div>
       <div>
           <div> { item.title } </div>
           <div className='right' > 
           <div> { item.count } x { formatCurrency( item.price ) }</div>
              <button className='button' onClick = { () => this.props.removeFromCart( item ) }>
                 Remove
              </button>
           </div>
       </div>
      </li>
))
```

anyone to help?? i'm stuck for this case, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure, that `cartItems` is a valid array, because if `cartItems` outputs something without map, it has to be an invalid array.

Comment: i'm not sure about this, but in reducer, i have set a state of this cart items like " state = { cartItems : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems')) || "[]" } "

Comment: Can you `console.log(cartItems);` before mapping over it and send me its output?

Comment: thanks, there is an error for condition of this state, which the "empty string ( [] ) is out of condition,

Comment: which is state = { cartItems : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems') || "[]" ) }